# How to create 2 new columns with appropriate prefix based on values in columns with same prefix in SAS Enterprise Guide / PROC SQL?

Tags: sas, aggregation, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

```
ID   | COUNT_COL_A | COUNT_COL_B | SUM_COL_A | SUM_COL_B
-----|-------------|-------------|-----------|------------
111  | 10          | 10          | 320       | 120
222  | 15          | 80          | 500       | 500
333  | 1           | 5           | 110       | 350
444  | 20          | 5           | 670       | 0
```

Requirements:

- I need to create new column "TOP_COUNT" where will be name of column (COUNT_COL_A or COUNT_COL_B) with the highest value per each ID,

  - if some ID has same values in both "COUNT_" columns take to "TOP_COUNT" column name which has higher value in its counterpart with prefix SUM_ (SUM_COL_A or SUM_COL_B)
- I need to create new column "TOP_SUM" where will be name of column (SUM_COL_A or SUM_COL_B) with the highest value per each ID,

  - if some ID has same values in both "SUM_" columns take to "TOP_SUM" column name which has higher value in its counterpart with prefix COUNT_ (COUNT_COL_A or COUNT_COL_B)

***It is not possible to have only 0 in columns with prefix _COUNT or only 0 in columns with prefix _SUM***

**There is not null in table**

Desire output:

```
ID   | COUNT_COL_A | COUNT_COL_B | SUM_COL_A | SUM_COL_B  | TOP_COUNT   | TOP_SUM
-----|-------------|-------------|-----------|------------|-------------|---------
111  | 10          | 10          | 320       | 120        | COUNT_COL_A | SUM_COL_A 
222  | 15          | 80          | 500       | 500        | COUNT_COL_B | SUM_COL_B  
333  | 1           | 5           | 110       | 350        | COUNT_COL_B | SUM_COL_B  
444  | 20          | 5           | 670       | 0          | COUNT_COL_A | SUM_COL_A
```

How can i do that in SAS Enterprise Guide or in PROC SQL ?

Comment: Why do you keep structuring the data in this way?  Why don't you just have ID, NAME, COUNT and SUM with multiple observations instead of multiple variables?  Then you just need to sort by the proper variables to find your answers.

Comment: Tom, I understand your point of view, but I need to have output like in question, do you have some idea, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create column with name of column with the highest value per each ID in SAS Enterprise Guide / PROC SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75177565/how-to-create-column-with-name-of-column-with-the-highest-value-per-each-id-in-s)

Comment: `Proc REPORT` and `Proc TABULATE` have very good flexibility for arranging aggregate computations.  Structure your data accordingly and use the Procs and ODS <destination> to create your output.

Comment: SQL is not well suited to looping over columns. Data step is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array with loops methodology:

- Declare an array of the count variables
- Set the maximum value to 0

  - Loop through the array
- Check if each value is more than current
  maximum
- If yes, assign value to current maximum value and store name

  - If no, keep looping

Non looping, function methodology:

- Use MAX to find the maximum value of the array
- Use WHICHN() to find the location of the array
- Use VNAME to get the variable name based on the location

```
*for count - you can extend for max;
data want;
    set have;

   array _count(*) count_col_:;

    *looping methodology;
    top_count_value=0;
    do i=1 to _count;
       if _count(i) > top_count_value then do;
          top_count = vname(_count(i));
          top_count_value = _count(i);
        end;
      end;

   /*or function methodology*/
   top_count_max = max(of _count(*));
   index_top_count = whichn(top_count_max, of _count(*));
   top_count_name_2 = vname(_count(index_top_count);

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the same thing as [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75177672/how-to-create-new-columns-with-names-of-columns-with-values-in-descending-order).  But because you want to transpose two sets of variable it is probably going to be easier to a data step and arrays to do the first transform.

```
data tall;
  set have;
  array counts count_col_a count_col_b;
  array sums sum_col_a sum_col_b;
  do index=1 to dim(sums);
    length type $5 name $32 ;
    type='COUNT';
    name=vname(counts[index]);
    value1=counts[index];
    value2=sums[index];
    output;
    type='SUM';
    name=vname(sums[index]);
    value1=sums[index];
    value2=counts[index];
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Now sort and take the last per ID/TYPE combination to find the largest.

```
proc sort;
  by id type value1 value2 name;
run;

data top;
  set tall;
  by id type value1 value2;
  if last.type;
run;
```

And then transpose and re-merge.

```
proc transpose data=top out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=TOP_;
  by id;
  id type;
  var name;
run;


data want;
  merge have want;
  by id;
run;
```

Result:

```
              COUNT_    COUNT_     SUM_     SUM_
Obs     ID     COL_A     COL_B    COL_A    COL_B     TOP_COUNT      TOP_SUM

 1     111      10        10       320      120     COUNT_COL_A    SUM_COL_A
 2     222      15        80       500      500     COUNT_COL_B    SUM_COL_B
 3     333       1         5       110      350     COUNT_COL_B    SUM_COL_B
 4     444      20         5       670        0     COUNT_COL_A    SUM_COL_A
```